# Why am I getting a Rails 3.2 jQuery Coffeescript syntax error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a controller called "organizations" with views.

I am trying to make a table in one of my views into a jQuery dataTable. I have done this a thousand times before this Coffeescript stuff.

I am running in dev mode, so I have no need to precompile my assets.

My application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And my organizations.js.coffee looks like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $.("#organizations").dataTable()
```

I am getting a syntax error on the open paren. What is my problem? This should be a simple task.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but shouldn't `$.("#organizations")` be `$("#organizations")` ? (without the dot)

Comment: I don't know either. Where did I get that dot? Thanks, it is working now.